# radio button php mailer form, submit radio values and prompt dialog upon sucess

Tags: php

```
<?php
  $backwheel = $_POST['backwheel'];
  $frontwheel = $_POST['frontwheel'];
  $form_message = "backwheel: $backwheel \nMessage: $message";

  mail("somecoolguy@gmail.com", "Email Subject", $form_message, "From: $email" );
?>
```

*(revised, above)*

For some reason; I cannot get the radio button form values in to submit at email. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="White"><img src="http://www..com/Imgs/wheel_whi.jpg">White</br>

<input type="radio" name="frontwheel" value="White"><img src="http://www..com/Imgs/wheel_whi.jpg">White</br>
```

**I would just like to send the selected radio button values to the specified email address and perhaps prompt 'Thanks for your submission'.**

Comment: Could you post the code that you are using for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
$form_message = "backwheel: $backwheel \nMessage: $message";
```

to

```
$form_message = "backwheel:".$backwheel." \nMessage:". $message;
```

Comment: so you are still facing problem... ?/

Comment: Yes, thanks for the input. Now it doesn't submit anything to email at all. I have the code in thee question above (revised).

Comment: change: `$form_message = "backwheel: $backwheel \nMessage: $message";` to  `$form_message = "backwheel:".$backwheel." \nMessage:". $message;`

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in the 2nd & 3rd lines of your PHP (missing semi-colons).  I'd start there.